# Backbone.js and SLIM framework PUT request

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, put, slim

I am trying to update my database table using SLIM framework PUT request from backbone.js VIEW. My backbonejs VIEW code is as below

```
var user_view = Backbone.View.extend(
    {               
        el: $("#wrappper"),
        initialize: function(data)
        {
            //alert(data.id);

            var user_data = {
                id: data.id,
                code: data.code
            };  

            var User_model = new user_model();             

            User_model.save(user_data,
            {
                success: function(response)
                {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    //alert(response);
                },
                error: function(response)
                {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(response));  

                    alert('No');
                }
            });                 
             return false;
        }

    });
```

My SLIM framework PUT request code is as below

```
$app->put('/user/:id/:code', function ($id,$code) use ($app, $db) {

    $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $users = $db->users()->where(array('user_id'=>$id,'user_code'=>$code));

    if ($users->fetch())
    {

        $post = (array) json_decode($app->request()->getBody());
        $data = $users->update($post);
    }


    echo json_encode($data);
});
```

My code is not working. I am getting alert **No**.

Can anyone say where is the porblem??

Thanks

**Update**

Request and response screenshot

[image]

Comment: Yes. The error message can tell you that.

Comment: @inf3rno thanks for your reply. Actually I am getting an alert **No**. What can be the solution ?? Thanks

Comment: The "response" object gives you the answer. Put this `console.log(response)` before `alert('no');`. In Chrome, click F12 and then click the "console" tab. Post the output here to help debugging

Comment: @Tivie thanks for your reply. I got these error messages .....................
.....................

GET http://localhost/backreq/library/underscore-min.map 404 (Not  Found) 


GET http://localhost/backreq/library/backbone-min.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Foysal That's not it. with the "Console" open perform the action that opens the alert('no') message.

Comment: @Tivie - Thanks for reply. Now I am getting following error in CONSOLE. --------------------

[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b000f (NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS) [nsICacheEntry.dataSize]" nsresult: "0x804b000f (NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://firebug/content/net/netCacheReader.js :: onDescriptorAvailable :: line 294" data: no]